# Is there a command line flag to unblock autoplay of video in firefox?

Tags: firefox, video, browser, autoplay, xvfb

I am trying to run a firefox instance with the help of Xvfb-run and play video in a tab. The video is set to autoplay on load, but firefox(>=66) has the default set to block audio and video. I want to set that flag to false, this could be done using the GUI ([link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay)) but I want to somehow do it using the CLI itself. Is there a way?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Comment: No, I already went through that and there isn't a way there. But I thought (like in chrome) there could be some undocumented flags.